# Java Function to rank and evaluate variables

Tags: java, double, rank, operation, utilization

I've got 4 double's

```
double newmanUtil = newmanYard.oreTonnes / time();
double yandi1Util = yandiMine1.oreTonnes / time();
double yandi2Util = yandiMine2.oreTonnes / time();
double miningAreaCUtil = miningAreaC.oreTonnes / time();
```

and I need an operation ( and loop) to rank the resulting numbers in order from least to greatest as four integers...

```
int NYRank = 0;
int Y1Rank = 0;
int Y2Rank = 0;
int MACRank = 0;
```

I feel like this is something simple that someone knows how to do quickly...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try it with Bubble Sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double newmanUtil = 1;
        double yandi1Util = 3;
        double yandi2Util = 2;
        double miningAreaCUtil = 4;

        List<Double> items = new ArrayList<Double>();
        items.add(newmanUtil);
        items.add(yandi1Util);
        items.add(yandi2Util);
        items.add(miningAreaCUtil);

        Collections.sort(items);

        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

I've replaced your variables with real values just to prove that it works.  Here's the output:

> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

What I did was take the values and put it in a list, then I sorted the list.  Java knows how to sort a list of `Double`s.

Comment: Hm, now how do I associate my rank vars with the array?

Comment: I don't know.  Tell me your inputs and your expected vs actual output.

Comment: just using your 1, 2, 3, 4 how do you get the array to check against the original doubles and give them a rank. In C i would use a function that would check if an object is in an array and return it's position...